# Two time comparision

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to compare two times, not getting how do.I not got any example .please tell me

```
SimpleDateFormat stDateSimple1 = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss");
String str1= (String)stDateSimple1.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println("str1-->"+str1);

String starttime="8:30:00";
String endtime="10:30:00";

if(starttime<str1 || endtime>str1  ){
    System.out.println("Display");
}else{
    System.out.println("Dont recortDisplay");
}
```

I tried this getting error please how can check time condition

Thanks,
 svn

Comment: means how to compare time they are in string

Comment: why dont you convert starttime and endtime to milliseconds and then compare?

Comment: `" 08:30:00"` and `" 10:30:00"` to match the SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has really nice methods, like `isBefore()`

[image]

Here is an example of usage:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String starttime="8:30:00";
String endtime="10:30:00";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime1 = fmt.parseDateTime(starttime);
DateTime dateTime2 = fmt.parseDateTime(endtime);


if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2)){
    System.out.println("awesome");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare Strings using `<` operator. You should instead format your time strings to a Date object and then compare those date objects

Something like this should work for you.

```
if (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(yourSring).compareTo(new Date()) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

As AM and PM are not there, it seems the time are in 24 hour format. If it is in 12 hour format, you have to use the format string `"hh:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
// AM/PM Format



public boolean compareTime(String t1, String t2) 
{
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

            long time1 = format.parse(t1).getTime();
            long time2 = format.parse(t2).getTime();
                return time1 > time2;
         } 
         catch(ParseException e)
         {
                return false;
         }      


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already have time set in `Calendar` instance use `compareTo()`, if you want to ignore date part, set it to some common value